# How can I implement OAuth 2 with Forms Authenticationon an already existing solution?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth

I have a website which uses Forms Authentication (ASP .NET).  Now, I'm trying to add OAuth 2 authentication (as I understand that, after many hours of studying, this is not the same thing as OpenID, and that OAuth2 can stand on its own now).

What I would like to happen, is I would like to have the user click a "sign on with google" button.  The user is redirected to Google, prompted for rights, and then after they hit OK my site picks up this login action (somehow, this is where I'm getting lost), gets their unique ID, and creates them a user account via forms authentication for them to log into the site with.

After about a week of this, I'm totally lost.

The Google site talks about implementing it via the handy "Login with Google" button. Which is great, but doesnt seem to want to talk to my web pages backend and set up logins etc (nary a mention of C# or ASP NET, which is okay, because I guess it has to be generalized).

Most other resources talk about implementing this with something called OWIN. I've nugett'd the packages for these, but I can't see where to "wire it up".

I've just got no idea. I spent a lot of time implementing OAuth 1 from an outdated web site only to have Google tell me that they no longer support that standard :(

More than happy to provide any source or structure from my project if it helps. This has got me banging my head up against a wall for now though.

Thanks.